# Open Terminal.app with directory from a given URL?

Tags: terminal, url

With the URL `<file:///Library/Fonts>` (for example in a note in [NV](http://notational.net/)) I can open the finder with the given location. Can I do something similar for the terminal? That is, if I write for example (doesn't work, that is the question!) `<terminal://Library/Fonts>` the Terminal.app should open a new window and cd to that directory.

Comment: Not without writing your own URL handler. I strongly recommend against it as it opens quite a security hole (unless you are really careful and know what you are doing).

Comment: The term you're looking for is a "protocol handler". It looks like you might be able to achieve what you want with a bit of AppleScript to wrap Terminal.app; see [this Apple Discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1280989?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: Thanks to you both. While I don't mind writing code I'll put this on hold for a while. I was silently hoping for a out of the box solution. If one of you put your comment into an answer I'd be happy to mark that as accepted.

Comment: “if I write” If you write it where? In a text file? In a shell script? At the command line?

Comment: @ChrisPage for example on the `open` command line: `open file:///foo/bar` or (as I wish) `open terminal://Library/Fonts`

Comment: See "Opening a New Terminal Programmatically" in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

### Opening a New Terminal Interactively

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal has a “New Terminal at Folder” Service you can enable in:

**System Preferences > Keyboard > Services > Files and Folders**

With this Service you can open a new terminal by selecting a folder or file path in any application and choosing this Service in the contextual menu (Control-Click or Right-Click) or the Services submenu in the application menu.

It doesn’t support “file:” URLs, but you can select the path part of the URL “/Library/Fonts” and use the Service with that.

There is also a “New Terminal Tab at Folder” Service.

### Opening a New Terminal Programmatically

If you need to open it from a command line or shell script, you can use the `open` command to tell Terminal to open a directory pathname or “file:” URL:

```
open -a Terminal file:///Library/Fonts
```

(This is equivalent to dragging a folder, file path or “file:” URL onto the Terminal application, which opens a new Terminal at that location.)

Answer (score 2):

This works from the command line:

```
/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal /Users/ &
```

Where /Users/ is the directory you want to set the working directory to.

Comment: I don't see how I could turn this into a URL?!

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you were trying to do.  You'd have to register a URL handler somehow.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595481/register-a-protocol-on-mac-osx

Looks like Terminal supports ssh, telnet, and x-man-page, but nothing else right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `open` command:

- `open .` opens Finder window for current directory
- `open /Library/Fonts` opens Finder window for `/Library/Fonts`
- `open http://www.apple.com/`
- `open ~/Documents/my-big-novel.pages`

Run `man open` for additional options.